# C++ How to instantiate an object with parameterised constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor

I have some understanding problems in C++ with parameterised constructors.
If I have a class with one constructor which have two function parameters, how can i instantiate it in an other class header file?

For example:

```
public:
      MyFunction myfunction(param1, param2); //makes an error
```

How can i declare an object like this?

Comment: "//makes an error" ... what error? That doesnt look like a proper declaration, or are `param1` and `param2` types?

Comment: "Expected a type specifier"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write `MyFunction myfunction;` in the class declaration.

Then in the *member initialiser list* of the constructor to the class of which `myfunction` is a member, write

```
/*Your constructor here*/ : myfunction(param1, param2)
{
    /*the constructor body*/
}
```

The bit after the colon is the member initialiser list. `param1` and `param2` are obviously *arguments* to that constructor.

Comment: Better answer than mine, and much more optimized

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways:

```
struct P
{
    P(int a, int b) :a(a), b(b){}

    int a;
    int b;
};

struct S
{
    S() : p1(4, 2) {} // initializer list

    P p1;
    P p2{4, 2}; // since c++11
    P p3 = P(4, 2); // since c++11
};
```

Comment: I like this a lot; but is it worth pointing out that `P p2{4, 2}` actually calls the constructor, unlike C?

Comment: Hmmm, nice, i will try this. What happens (in the background) if i use this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the problem is that `MyFunction` has only one constructor that only accepts two arguments.

You can use a pointer to that object and then initialize it in the constructor:

```
#include <memory>

class Something {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<MyFunction> data;
        Something(int par1, int par2) {
            data = std::shared_ptr<MyFunction>(new MyFunction(par1, par2)); // here you go!
        }

        ~Something() {
            //delete data; no need to do this now
        }
};
```

**Edit:** added a smart pointer to follow rule of three.

Comment: @Jarod42, I'm new to C++, so my question might sound silly: what is 'rule of 3/5/0'?

Comment: Yeah it's a nice way :) But this is the only solution? Use pointers / smart poinsters for this?

Comment: no, it's not the only one. See the answer of @Bathsheba  for another way to do this. The way shown in my answer is the simplest one, to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

An option is having a predeclaration and a pointer to the class.

```
classA.h
class A
{
    public:
    A(a,b);
};

classB.h
class A;
class B{
    public:
    A* foo;
    B();
    ~B();
}

classB.cpp
#include classA.h
#include classB.h
B()
{
    foo=new A(a,b);
}
~B()
{
    delete(foo);
}
```